# NHibernate search criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have class Definition with property string Data

```
public class Definition
{
  string Type  {get; set; }
  string Data  { get; set; }
}
```

Then Data contains some XML that saved as string

```
<Definition>
    <Property>
     <Key>DefinitionId</Key>
     <Value>5</Value>
    </Property>   
</Definition>
```

I need to get all Definitons where DefinitionId is 5.

What the best way to do it?
To get all definitions and parsed them or i can do something with NHibernate?

Answer (score 1):

You can query Xml types with NHibernate if your DB supports Xml querying.
Assuming you're working with Sql Server 2005+ ...

**Step 1 - *Class Definition***

Change your class Definition to:

```
public class Definition
{
  string Type  {get; set; }
  XDocument Data  { get; set; }
}
```

Your mapping should pick the XDocument type and create a the appropriate `Xml` column type for the `Data` column in the database.

**Step 2 - *Querying***

A couple of different ways to query, but they boil down to the same thing. The code below shows the querying via the QueryOver api:

```
session.QueryOver<Definition>()
       .Where
        (
            Restrictions.Eq
            (
                Projections.SqlProjection
                (
                   "Data.value('(/Definition/Property/Value)[1]', 'int') as DefinitionId",
                   new string[] { "DefinitionId" },
                   new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Int32 }
                ),
                5
            )
        )
       .List();
```

The above query uses standard Sql Server XQuery to query the Xml field. A little introduction on XQuery language: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/27/sql-server-introduction-to-discovering-xml-data-type-methods-a-primer/

Comment: Also, there is session.CreateSqlQuery() to submit adhoc SQL queries, yet have NHibernate build objects from the returned data.